# WAVE reports "missing alt text" with alternative text presented

Tags: wave, wcag

Why does wave reports X amount of images missing alternative text with the alternative text presented?
For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are pointing to the right piece of code. I ran the [WAVE tool](https://wave.webaim.org/extension/) on https://facadoro.com/, which appears to be the website you're checking.

I do get some unlabeled images but notice some of the icons have full color (the first 3) but the rest are faded out.

[image]

If you hover the mouse over a faded one, you get a tooltip that the faded icons are for elements that are hidden (possibly because of CSS `display:none`).

[image]

In your screenshot, some of the icons are full color and some are faded. If I look at the full color ones, while the images **do** have alt text, it's the null string (alt=""). That tells the screen reader that the image is decorative and to ignore it.

```html
<a href="https://facadoro.com/syllogi-arret-empneysmeni-apo-ti-dynami-ton-gynaikon/">
  <img src=".../05-arret-1024x576.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image" alt=""> 
  <span class="pf-icon pf-icon-link"></span>
  <div class="item--overlay"></div>
</a>
```

However, this image is **inside** of a link and the link does not have any text so WAVE is telling you that the link doesn't have any text and the image doesn't have any alt text so the screen reader won't know what to announce.  Notice the WAVE error says "Linked image missing alternative text". "Linked image" means the image is inside of a link.

This happens with 3 of the 4 images near the bottom:

[image]

If I look at one the faded icons, it points to the pictures further down the page.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Which has the following code.

```html
<div class="instagram-item">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CodBQD3oaZ5/" title="Show him...">
    <span class="item--overlay">
      <i class="fa-instagram"></i>
    </span>
    <img src="...9138795735649093906_n.jpg" alt="Show him...">
  </a>
</div>
```

```html
<style>
.instagram-item > a img {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

As you can see, there is a valid `alt` text on the <img> but since the image is hidden (because of `display:none`), the alt text will be ignored. Unlike the case above, where the alt text was blank and the link didn't have any other text, **this** link **does** have text that a screen reader can announced because of the `title` attribute ("show him...").

I think it's questionable that these faded icons should even be flagged at all.

But in summary, I'm not sure if the code you are pointing to in your screenshot is the code that's in error.  If it indeed is that code, you may have to look at the CSS for the image to see if the image is hidden.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I think you're right. I've tried so many solutions but never came up with something like yours...

Comment: @meidanisalekos i have the same issue, how did you fix it?

Comment: @Leb_Broth. you might not have anything to "fix". Are you running WAVE? Are you looking at "Errors" or "Alerts" or "Structural Elements", etc? Only the "Errors" section are possible WCAG failures. The other areas might be suggestions but not required. But even the "Errors" need to be reviewed for accuracy. You can post a new question and tag with "wave", "wcag", and "accessibility" if you want more feedback.

Comment: @slugolicious i just did post